# "Error of type eDSAuthFailed (-14090)" when attempting to disable a user in Workgroup Manager

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mac-osx-server

In Mac OS Server 10.6, when I select a user account, uncheck the "access account" checkbox, and click Save, I get this error message:

```
Error of type eDSAuthFailed (-14090) on line 3912 of /SourceCache/WorkgroupManager/WorkgroupManager-361.3.1/Plugins/UserAccounts/UserAdvancedPluginView.mm
```

It happen for all user accounts I've tried.  I'm able to make changes to other attributes (e.g., passwords); I just can't disable accounts.

Any ideas about how to fix this, or to work around it in order to disable user accounts?

#### Already Tried

- `changeip -checkhostname` says "The names match. There is nothing to change."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Workgroup Manager, there are two levels of authentication: first there's the "Workgroup Manager Connect" dialog, then there's the authentication bar just below the main window's toolbar.  For the second authentication, I was `diradmin`, which was failing.  I deleted my Keychain entry for that, restarted Workgroup Manager, then, for the second authentication, authenticated as `root`.  Root was able to successfully disable the user account.

This is strange, because `diradmin` has the "administer this server" permission, which I would have thought would include permission to disable users.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to understand what's happening :

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3186 will help you understanding what's happening by checking more detailed directory services logs.

First steps would be to unbind / rebind clients if you remote the server access from Workgroup Manager on a client.

---

> If you just want to resolve this :

Open Directory issues are really annoying to resolve, can be related a thousand of things.
If your network schema is not too interlinked to third party systems, I would advise you to backup your users/groups/computer.

/Utilities/Workgroup Manager, Export (Password are not saved)
Then you set the OD as standalone, and master again, it will recreate the LDAP and Kerberos
/Utilities/Workgroup Manager, Import (You have to set new password for users).

note : Promoting a OD to Master then reimporting user account won't reset your collaborative services data such as wiki, web, PosGres, address book, calendars... etc

You can -otherwise- archive the OD(password remain intact for accounts), then restore, but it is probable that you restore the issue in the meantime.